# How to make width at 100% on a table work in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, width, css-tables

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

doesn't seem to do anything at all on IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knew the answer, just didn't find it on SO, I think it belongs here.

You have to set the margin to make it work:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try
     table{
            table-layout:fixed;
        }

I had the same issue making the table 100% width in IE8.

Comment: This should be the answer